# Install Go Programming Language on Ubuntu core (snappy)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, go, wget, snapcraft

I tried to install Go language on Ubuntu Core (snappy) for creating a web server. How to do it? I have problem downloading go-lang archive because there is no 'wget' in ubuntu core. Any solutions?

Comment: You can use browser to download the archive.

Comment: No, I mean from command line.

Comment: Maybe `curl` is installed, you can use it instead of `wget`. Or just install `wget`.

Comment: curl isn't installed too.. I tried to search "wget" package on snappy (snappy search wget) but no results

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what your use case is, but if you're trying to deploy a go webserver to your Ubuntu server it's worth noting that you don't need "go" installed to run go binaries. If your issue is literally just: you don't know how to move any file to the server... ftp? links?

Answer (score 4):

In general, Snappy should be viewed as a deployment target rather than a development system.  It is similar to Android or iOS in this way, depending on a second system for development.

So the usual way to deploy a Go application on Snappy would be something like:

1. build the application on your development system.
2. package the binaries as a `.snap` package
3. deploy the package on Snappy (either by releasing it through the store, or copying it to the target system manually).

Steps (1) and (2) are probably best done using the [Snapcraft](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/snapcraft/) tool, which has built-in support for building Go applications.  The last can be done using the `snappy install` command on the target system.

One thing to note is that Snapcraft doesn't do anything to help you with cross-compiling yet, so if your chosen development system has a different architecture you may run into problems (e.g. if you are developing on x86 and want to deploy to a Raspberry Pi).

If this is the case, one option here is to use LXC containers to create a traditional Ubuntu system in a container on the target system.  You should be able to set it up with commands like the following (based on [this post](https://plus.google.com/+St%C3%A9phaneGraber/posts/aX6vogzEQ1X)):

```
sudo snappy install lxd
lxc remote add images images.linuxcontainers.org
lxc launch images:ubuntu/vivid/armhf dev
```

You can then get a shell within the container using:

```
lxc exec dev bash
```

From there you can install Go and Snapcraft, and build an ARM version of your package ready to be installed outside of the container (or onto other ARM devices).

Comment: Thanks! I've decided to use Docker as a container on Snappy, then I install nginx on it as a web server. Basically, I want to make an environment that uses Ubuntu-core as OS. And that environment act as a web server. Did I do the right thing?

Comment: That is certainly one way you can run a web application on top of Snappy.  In your question you asked about running Go apps on Snappy, so I answered how you could deploy directly to the platform.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use classic mode:

```
$ sudo snap install classic --edge --devmode
$ classic
```